# MS SQL Server: How to alias a linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is regarding MS SQL Server.
I have two DB servers for my application named Torch

TorchProd and TorchTest are the db servers.
There is also a data mining server DataMineProd and DataMineTest
I have linked servers to these shown below...

TorchProd has a link to DataMineProd

TorchTest has a link to DataMineTest

I have a proc called TorchCRUD. Inside that proc is this sql...

```html
select * from DataMineTest.mydatabase.dbo.mytable
```

If I push this proc up to production it will fail because it can't find DataMineTest. It could find DataMineProd How do I create an alias such that I can move this proc freely from Test to Prod?

Comment: [Create linked servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)